# how to alter new column with a data from a select statement

Tags: mysql, alter

I have two tables:

```
1: Table1
id      code    CUSTOMER_NAME   PRODUCT_NAME                PRICE
11297   1000    The pub         Fanta                       57.5
12345   1200    Bub 1           Coke                        20.4
```

2: Table2

```
id      PRODUCT_NAME

1       Fanta
2       Sprite
3       Coke
```

Now what I want to get is to Insert all distinct clients from Table1 as a new column into my Table2.

I was trying something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER_NAME FROM Table1 INTO Table2 and ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD CUSTOMER_NAME longtext;
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER_NAME FROM Table1 and ALTER TABLE Table2 ADD CUSTOMER_NAME longtext;
```

What I want to get: 
2: Table2

```
id      PRODUCT_NAME    The pub    Pub 1    ...     ...

1       Fanta
2       Sprite
3       Coke
```

But none of them works.. How to solve this problem? 
Cheers.

Comment: This is not a good db design. Why are you trying to do so?

Comment: It makes no sense to store product name in table 1

Comment: I have one table with all informations like customer name, product, price etc. I want to get this data in a form of a spreadsheet so first column will be the product, and next columns will be all customer names and then just fill it  up with the prices in ascending order.